# "Permission denied" for a custom content filter in Postfix

Tags: permissions, email, postfix

I've created a simple content filter as a python script, for Postfix:

```
$ ls -al /home/main_user/test1.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vmail2 nobody /home/main_user/test1.py
```

In `/etc/postfix/master.cf` I have this:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd 
  -o content_filter=filter1:dummy

# [........................]

filter1    unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
    flags=Rq user=vmail2 null_sender=
    argv=/home/main_user/test1.py -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Error in the logs of Postfix:

```
fatal: pipe_command: execvp /home/main_user/test1.py Permission denied
```

**vmail2** - is a user with no home directory. I've created it specifically for this task:

```
$ id vmail2
uid=5002(vmail2) gid=5002(vmail2) groups=5002(vmail2)
```

Why does it fail and how to fix it?

Comment: Is `/home` mounted `noexec`? Does Postfix have access to `/home` and `/home/main_user`?

Comment: @Mikel I don't know. Probably not. How do I check?

Comment: @Mikel "Does Postfix have access to /home and /home/main_user" --> also, how do I check? I think not